# using Row_Number() - Finding Maximum Registration

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I would like to find out the maximum exam paper registration on each course using row_number() function.

Registration Table

```
CourseID  StudentName  PaperCode

 101    David   10001
 101    David   20000
 101    George  10000
 102    Peter   10000
 102    Peter   20000
 102    David   20000
```

The expected result could be

```
CourseID| StudentName | NumberofRegistration

101       David     2
102      Peter       2
```

I tried with the follwoing query and unable to extend it to attain the desired result.

```
select 

         CourseID,
         StudentName,
         NumberOfRegistration
from

(
  select 
         CourseID,
         StudentName,
         ROW_NUMBER() 
         over( 
              partition by count(papercode)
              order by CourseID asc) as NumberOfRegistration
```

from
         Registration
        group by CourseID,StudentName
 )x

Please help me to complete it.

Comment: Why you expecting `CourseID==101` and not `102` for David?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @T table
(
  CourseID int,
  StudentName varchar(10),
  PaperCode int
)

insert into @T values
(101,    'David',   10001),
(101,    'David',   20000),
(101,    'George',  10000),
(102,    'Peter',   10000),
(102,    'Peter',   20000),
(102,    'David',   20000)

select CourseID, StudentName, NumberofRegistration
from
  (
    select CourseID, StudentName, NumberofRegistration,
           row_number() over(partition by CourseID order by NumberofRegistration desc) as rn
    from
      (
        select CourseID, StudentName, count(*) as NumberofRegistration
        from @T
        group by CourseID, StudentName
      ) as T
  ) as T
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this:

**Test data**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(CourseID INT,StudentName VARCHAR(100),PaperCode INT)

INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES
    (101,'David',10001),
    (101,'David',20000),
    (101,'George',10000),
    (102,'Peter',10000),
    (102,'Peter',20000),
    (102,'David',20000)
```

**Query**

like Mikael Eriksson said this will work in SQL Server 2005/2008. But it will not work in SQL Server 2012.

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tbl.CourseID ORDER BY tbl.CourseID) AS RowNumber,
        COUNT(PaperCode) OVER(PARTITION BY tbl.CourseID, tbl.[StudentName]) AS NumberofRegistration,
        CourseID,
        StudentName,
        PaperCode
    FROM
        @tbl AS tbl
)
SELECT
    CTE.CourseID,
    CTE.StudentName,
    CTE.NumberofRegistration
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    CTE.RowNumber=1
```

But this will work in SQL Server 2012:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        COUNT(CourseID) OVER(PARTITION BY tbl.CourseID,tbl.StudentName) AS NumberofRegistration,
        tbl.CourseID,
        tbl.StudentName,
        tbl.PaperCode
    FROM
        @tbl AS tbl 
)
, CTE2
AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CTE.CourseID ORDER BY CTE.NumberofRegistration DESC) AS RowNumber,
        CTE.NumberofRegistration,
        CTE.CourseID,
        CTE.StudentName,
        CTE.PaperCode
    FROM
        CTE
)
SELECT
    CTE2.CourseID,
    CTE2.StudentName,
    CTE2.NumberofRegistration
FROM
    CTE2
WHERE
    CTE2.RowNumber=1
```

**Result**

```
CourseID| StudentName | NumberofRegistration
101       David           2
102       Peter           2
```

Comment: There is something fishy going on with this query. You get the expected result in SQL Server 2005/2008 but not in SQL Server 2012. I think you need to include `NumberofRegistration` in the `order by`for the row_number. Otherwise you can't be sure that you will actually get the highest value of `NumberofRegistration` for `RowNumber=1`.

Comment: ok. I just tested on sql server 2008 and it worked. Let me see if i can update it

Comment: Great thanks for you input. Do you have any idé why it work on 2005/2008 and not on 2012?

Comment: The query plans are different. There is an extra `sort` step in the 2008 version.